# How to enable delete local storage permission in the edge extension

Tags: javascript, html, microsoft-edge

I have made an web app with js to store notes using local storage. It's working completely fine.

But when I turned it into a edge extension I am not able to delete the notes which is actually the data in the local storage.But I am able to add notes. Deleting notes not happening.

Is their any specific permission  I have to give in manifest file.

Comment: Could we see some code? It would give a much better idea of what might be wrong. But off the bat I would say to ensure you are accessing local storage from the window object as there has been known issues with Edge and local storage in the past.

Comment: May be their are some issues. As when I opening it as a website then it's working completely fine. But in extension giving problem.  In Local storage  the object is not getting created .

Comment: https://notetodoarnab.000webhostapp.com/    my website link. U can check it it's working completely fine. But in extension it is giving problem in deleting notes.

Comment: It does work very well on the web page. Are you using [chrome.storage](https://developer.chrome.com/docs/extensions/reference/storage/#manifest)? If this is the case, you need to declare the API permissions in the manifest.

Comment: How to declare local storage permission in the manifest?

Comment: If you are using the chrome.storage I mentioned, you can refer to the example in the document: [chrome.storage-manifest](https://developer.chrome.com/docs/extensions/reference/storage/#manifest).

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.